# unable to update i:386 packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, ppa

I tried to update my repos using `sudo apt-get update` and I get this error.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glimpse-hackers/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glimpse-hackers/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/zram/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/zram/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no packages for trusty in these PPAs. Remove the confronting PPAs to solve the error.

Open 'Software Sources' and go to 'Other Software' tab and choose the desired PPA from the list (in your case the glimpse-hackers and shnatsel PPAs). Afterwards click on Remove to remove them. Refer [this](http://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/) link to know more.

You can also use command-line. see [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Answer (score 1):

This is normally due to the ppa repositories you've added no longer serving content from that address. They may have been moved, or shut down, it could even be due to a typing error.

I'd suggest you check whether the sources still exist manually, by checking the developers' websites. You may need to edit the entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory to use the correct URL.

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92897/320386) has a lot of useful tips for the situation you're in.

Comment: Is there any way for me to find the new websites if the ones on my repo list no longer work?